# Animation CSS Tag not working with ID, 0% to 100%

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Simple issue, but I cant seem to get my keyframe img animation to work on my site. The HTML for the img is like this:

```
<img src="img address" id="logo" class="center">
```

My CSS for the class center:

```
.center{display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
```

And the CSS for the @keyframe:

```
@keyframes logo_invert{ 0% {filter:invert(0%)} 50% {filter:invert(100%)} 100% {filter:invert(0%)} }
```

And finally the CSS for the logo:

```
#logo{width:500px; length:500px; animation-name:logo_invert; animation-duration:6s; animation-iteration-count:infinite;}
```

I am very much confused as to what is wrong here, as my testing elsewhere worked for this fine. I am using the current version of chrome for the site, if that may change anything.

Answer (score 1):

First guess would be remove the `length` thing in your css since it's not a valid property, beyond that works fine... Cheers.

```css
.center{
  display:block;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto
}

#logo {
  width:500px;
  /* length:500px; - This isn't a real thing, so commenting out. */
  animation-name: logo_invert; 
  animation-duration: 6s; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

img { 
  height: 10rem;
  object-fit: contain;
}

@keyframes logo_invert { 
  50% { filter:invert(100%) }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVW9D.jpg" id="logo" class="center">
```

Comment: Oh,right, it would be height:500px; and not length:500px; , wondering what was wrong. Funny.